# How do I check before updating the table contents in php with IF Statement in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement

How I check before Update with IF Statement
if <=0 *(minus)* set to 0

```
$sql="UPDATE tblemployees SET AnnualLeaveRights = 0 (IF(AnnualLeaveRights <=0)) WHERE EmpId=:empid";
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't touch rows that you don't intend to alter.

```
$sql= "UPDATE tblemployees
       SET AnnualLeaveRights = 0
       WHERE EmpId=:empid
         AND AnnualLeaveRights < 0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
$sql="UPDATE tblemployees 
      SET AnnualLeaveRights = IF(AnnualLeaveRights <= 0, 0, AnnualLeaveRights) 
      WHERE EmpId=:empid";
```

You can also use the [`Greatest()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function instead:

```
$sql="UPDATE tblemployees 
      SET AnnualLeaveRights = GREATEST(0,AnnualLeaveRights) 
      WHERE EmpId=:empid";
```

Comment: @RhonyRenyah happy to help :) Do consider marking it as accepted answer (green tick). thanks

Comment: I don't reckon I'd query either of these ways.

Comment: @mickmackusa what would be your way ? using case .. when ?

Comment: Im slow on my phone.

Comment: mickmackusa is right IMO - don't fixate on the IF logic, this is something simple best solved by conventional SQL set-based operations using WHERE. As well as producing simpler code, doing it that way should perform better as well, because less rows are processed and there are no extra functions to execute.

Comment: @ADyson and mickmackusa - As far as I know, MySQL optimizer does not update a field if there is no value to be changed in it. So, it is hardly a performance boost in my understanding. Logically, yes mickmacusa's answer is simpler

Comment: of course it may not update the field, but it has to run the function in order to determine whether it needs to be updated or not, and that's what might be slow. Whereas with a WHERE clause, the row is never selected in the first place. And since that's based on standard SQL operations, it's likely to be much more highly optimised. It can potentially take advantage of any indexes, caching etc. On modern hardware, unless the dataset is very large you might not notice a big performance difference, but at a large scale it could start to be important.

Comment: Looking at the two different query plans might be useful in order to see how mySQL would process the data.

Comment: @ADyson what if there is no indexing on `AnnualLeaveRights`. Agree, `EXPLAIN` statement should clear out better.

Comment: The indexing would only be an _extra_ bonus, it's not the only reason why a WHERE clause would be likely to be more performant.